# How to sequentially transition to different QStates after single button click

Tags: c++, qt

I have an image displayed on a QGraphicsView and I'm trying to make it move using a state machine. After clicking the image I want it to move down by 200px and then across to the right another 200px. This is the code I have so far but the issue is that instead of the image moving in the L shape as desired it moves diagonally i.e. instead of transitioning from state 1 to state 2 and then to state 3, the animation transitions state 1 to state 3 skipping state 2.

```
stateMachine = new QStateMachine(this);

QState *state_01 = new QState(stateMachine);
QState *state_02 = new QState(stateMachine);
QState *state_03 = new QState(stateMachine);

state_01->assignProperty(pixmap, "pos", QPointF(0, 0));
state_02->assignProperty(pixmap, "pos", QPointF(0, 200));
state_03->assignProperty(pixmap, "pos", QPointF(200, 200));

QAbstractTransition *transition_01 = state_01->addTransition(pixmap, SIGNAL(pixmapPressed()), state_02);
QAbstractTransition *transition_02 = state_02->addTransition(state_03);

transition_01->addAnimation(new QPropertyAnimation(pixmap, "pos"));
transition_02->addAnimation(new QPropertyAnimation(pixmap, "pos"));

stateMachine->setInitialState(state_01);
stateMachine->start();
```

I think I'm probably misusing the statement for the transition of state 2 to state 3 but I've tried other methods without success. The only other idea I haven't tried would be to check if the image has reached it's position for state 2 and somehow emit a signal to start the next transition to state 3 but I feel that maybe what I'm asking for can all be done with the state machine framework. How can I get the image to move through the 3 states after clicking on the image only once to start the entire process?

Comment: Hi, well i'm not surprised about the behavior of your program. There is no link between your state machine and your GUI so it's impossible to now when the image has moved down. The solution you mentionned could work yes. An other one could be to trigger the transition from 2 to 3 with a signal, and emit this signal after a certain period of time using a QTimer.

Comment: @Martin - I don't understand why you would say there's no link between the state machine and gui. My code follows the general pattern I see from the documentation and doc examples. Maybe I've missed something but isn't the "link" created between gui elements and the state machine by assigning properties to different states which in turn are managed by the state machine?

Comment: Yes you're right, i told you a mistake, there is a link. What I wanted to say is what do you mean by: "I want it to move down and THEN across to the right". Is it a slowly slide down (during 1s) and then on the right ? In this case, your state machine doesn't know when your image is in the bottom. That's what I wanted to say with "there is no link". What happen is that when you reach state2, you go to 3 very quickly. So your coordinates are (0,200) during a so small period of time that you can see your image in the bottom (and probably not moving down at all).

Answer (score 0):

To delay a transition until its animation has completed, you need to wait for the propertiesAssigned() signal of QState.

For example:

```
QAbstractTransition *transition_02 = state_02->addTransition(state_03);
```

will become:

```
QAbstractTransition *transition_02 = state_02->addTransition(state_02, SIGNAL(propertiesAssigned()), state_03);
```

Read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html#detecting-that-all-properties-have-been-set-in-a-state for more information.